# VueJS (another) virtual scroll implementation

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to implement virtual scroll for items with variable heights. Every other implementation I've seen so far requires you to specify the height when declaring the module.

I have the list implemented as follows:

```
<div 
    class="main" 
    ref="main" 
    @scroll="handleScroll"
    >
    <div :style="{
            'margin-top':padTop+'px',
            'margin-bottom':padBottom()+'px'
        }">
        <div v-for="i in maxDisplayed">
            <slot :name="'s-' + (i + startIndex - 1)">{{i + startIndex - 1}}</slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `handleScroll` function (the one failing) is this:

```
handleScroll (e) {
    if (!this.$refs.main || this.$refs.main.scrollTop == undefined) return; //can't calculate if there's nothing displayed
    // top of the items list container relative to the page top
    let mainTop = this.$refs.main.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
    // bottom position of the first "displayed" item
    let itemTop = this.$refs.main.children[0].children[0].children[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let itemBottom = this.$refs.main.children[0].children[0].children[0].getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    if (itemBottom < mainTop && (Object.keys(this.$slots).length > (this.startIndex + this.maxDisplayed))) { 
        this.startIndex ++;
        this.heights.push(this.$refs.main.children[0].children[0].children[0].clientHeight);
    }
    else if (itemTop > mainTop && (this.startIndex > 0)) {
        this.heights.pop();
        this.startIndex = Math.max(this.startIndex - 1, 0);
    }
},
```

So far I have the code working perfectly when user is scrolling relatively slowly. But it fails when you scroll fast through the list.  I suspect it has something to do with it not being able to catch all the children flying past the scroll window. Any help would be appreciated.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oah89oyp/)

Comment: Have you tried to use a plugin instead of doing it yourself? this might help: https://github.serafin.io/vuebar/

Comment: the vuebar doesn't really give me an advantage if there are 20k elements in the list - it still gets slow. hence why i'm trying to implement virtual scrolling - it hides the "invisible" elements from dom so it doesn't slow down the page

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. Have you achieved more results?

Comment: Nothing to my satisfaction, I started using paging instead